# How to compile jsp pages as per tomcat 7 standard

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat, ant, apache-tomee

Our code is moving from jboss to tomEE and found some issues with jsp pages which was working with JBOSS
as per link 
http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/10/tomcat-7-jstl-failed-to-parse.html 
 there are some differences so that jboss and tomcat finds differences for IDENTIFIER CHECK

AS per link i need to change following format for my jsp pages b4 moving to Tomee from Jboss 
Change the code from ${client.new} to ${client['new']}

in short is it possible i can compile all jsp pages via Maven so that at compile time itself i can identify how many jsp pages we have to change